# Nested Integrals Using NIntegrate Not Converging

Tags: numerical-integration, integral-equations

I have a mathematica script/code that I wrote that involves a few nested NIntegrate functions but its not converging. I let it run for about a week before calling it quits. I am a beginner with Mathematica and composed this script looking through the manual, so I am hoping there is a better way of solving this and that this problem is not just numerically impossible.

Can any help?

```
e = 1.60217733*10^-19;
re = 2.81794092*10^-15;
gamma = 1000/0.510999060000000;
n = (200*10^-12)/e;
sigmaZ = 10*10^-6;
lambda = n/sigmaZ;
Xt = 100*10^-6;
lq = 0.1;
k = 2;
phiM = lq*k*Xt;
rhoM = lq/phiM;
drift = 10;


EFieldKernel[Xi_?NumericQ, d_?NumericQ, s_?NumericQ, sprime_?NumericQ] := 
(Xi/Xt) (2 n*lambda)/(Xt - Xi - 
    d*((d - s + sprime - Sqrt[d^2 + (Xi - Xt)^2])/(-rhoM + (
   d (rhoM + Xi - Xt))/Sqrt[d^2 + (Xi - Xt)^2])) - 
1/2 rhoM*((
  d - s + sprime - Sqrt[d^2 + (Xi - Xt)^2])/(-rhoM + (
   d (rhoM + Xi - Xt))/Sqrt[d^2 + (Xi - Xt)^2]))^2); 


EFieldLongitudinal[Xi_?NumericQ, d_?NumericQ, s_?NumericQ] := 
 NIntegrate[EFieldKernel[Xi, d, s, sprime], {sprime, 0, sigmaZ}]

EFieldNegativeSum[d_?NumericQ, s_?NumericQ] := 
 NIntegrate[-EFieldLongitudinal[Xi, d, s], {Xi, 
   Xt - rhoM (1 - Cos[phiM]) - d*Sin[phiM], Xt}]
EfieldPositiveSum[d_?NumericQ, s_?NumericQ] := 
 NIntegrate[
  EFieldLongitudinal[Xi, d, s], {Xi, -Xt, 
   Xt - rhoM (1 - Cos[phiM]) - d*Sin[phiM]}]

wake[d_?NumericQ, 
  s_?NumericQ] := (re/gamma*phiM) (EFieldNegativeSum[d, s]) + (re/
 gamma*-phiM) (EfieldPositiveSum[d, s])
Etot[s_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[wake[d, s], {d, 0, drift}]

Erms = Sqrt[
  NIntegrate[lambda*Etot[s]^2, {s, 0, sigmaZ}] - 
  NIntegrate[lambda*Etot[s], {s, 0, sigmaZ}]^2]
```

Comment: You have lots of undefined variables, e.g., lambda, n, re, gamma, phiM, etc. You should provide example values for them. Next, I believe the best way to compute a nested `NIntegrate` function is to rewrite it as a single `NIntegrate`, and let `NIntegrate` figure out what method to use.

Comment: You can do this `Integrate[(Xi/Xt) (2 n*lambda)/(Xt - Xi - 
    d*((d - s + sprime - Sqrt[d^2 + (Xi - Xt)^2])/(-rhoM + (
   d (rhoM + Xi - Xt))/Sqrt[d^2 + (Xi - Xt)^2])) - 
1/2 rhoM*((
  d - s + sprime - Sqrt[d^2 + (Xi - Xt)^2])/(-rhoM + (
   d (rhoM + Xi - Xt))/Sqrt[d^2 + (Xi - Xt)^2]))^2), {sprime, 0, sigmaZ}]` operation analytically. Maybe this would help.

Comment: You are correct! So sorry I forgot the variables, this should be more helpful. l tried @RolfMertig suggestion, but it still does not converge. Any one else with some thoughts?

Comment: What do you mean by "does not converge" Does the integration fail with errors? Or does it not finish?

Comment: @CarlWoll It does not finish. No errors. I think I let it run for about a week last time.  But, even if it just takes a lot of time I was hoping there was a formalism or technique that could speed it up.

Answer (score 1):

In general, it is much better to use a single [`NIntegrate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NIntegrate) instead of using multiple nested integrals. Here is a contrived example:

```
f[x_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[g[x t], {t, 0, 10}];
g[x_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[Cos[u], {u, 0, x}];

NIntegrate[f[x], {x,0,1}] //AbsoluteTiming
```

> {4.70959, 2.92526}

The equivalent single [`NIntegrate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NIntegrate) version is:

```
NIntegrate[Cos[u], {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 10}, {u, 0, x t}] //AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.441031, 2.92526}

The timing discrepancy can easily be much worse, if the nested [`NIntegrate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NIntegrate) has integration convergence issues, which is what I think you're experiencing.

I took a look at your code, replacing all `_?NumericQ` patterns with just `_`, and replacing all [`NIntegrate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NIntegrate) heads with `Inactive[NIntegrate]`. Then it was a relatively simple exercise to convert the nested [`NIntegrate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NIntegrate) objects into multiple unnested [`NIntegrate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NIntegrate) objects. When I did this, the [`NIntegrate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NIntegrate) finished quickly, but had convergence issues. I think this solves your speed issue. You could ask about the convergence issues in a different question.